# Cursors.Hand not respecting system configuration

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouse-cursor

I am working with a VB.NET user control which should use the hand cursor when the mouse is over it.

This bit does work - when the cursor is on top of the control, we get a hand. A bug has been reported by the customer, which I have been able to reproduce, that when the hand cursor is changed in the Windows mouse settings it still uses the Windows default cursor. The arrow cursor does update.

`Me.Parent.Control.Cursor = Cursors.Hand`

What am I missing to get this to use the correct one? I'm guessing there's an easier way than going to the registry to find the hand cursor for the current user and loading that in as a custom cursor object?

I have tried to do a Google search for this, but I am only finding results for different environments (CSS, etc), or articles about what a cursor is.

Comment: Some Cursors use pre-defined `.cur` resources (calls `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`), not the System's, even though [IDC_HAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw) is defined.

Comment: I don't remember why that is. Probably because it uses `LoadCursor()` (or maybe this function is used explicitly, to provide default Cursors across the platform). You can load it yourself. Using [LoadImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew), not `LoadCursor()` as .Net Framework does.